# How to understand the structure of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I read a sentence from [this article in](http://www.economist.com/news/europe/21606298-parents-fret-over-how-long-children-should-stay-school-gymnasium-revolt) the Economist but I can't understand its structure.

The sentence is:

> For a country that sees itself as egalitarian, this smacks of class privilege—those going to Gymnasium tend to be disproportionately well-off.

I couldn't find the predicate of this sentence.

Comment: I'm just curious, did you recognize _smacks_ as a verb?

Comment: Ahhh..I notice that smacks is a verb here.I only knew the noun definition and I was confused by the clauses.Thank you very much! With the answers below I understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually two complete clauses joined together with punctuation. It's not ideal style, but it is fairly common in journalism.

> "For a country that sees itself as egalitarian, this smacks of class privilege"

Core sentence: *This smacks of class privilege*. Meaning, "this has the appearance of class privilege"--of giving special access to public goods to one particular social class or subgroup of society (usually the wealthy).

Add the modifying prepositional phrase "For a country that sees itself as egalitarian". Prepositional phrases are often used at the beginning of a sentence to "set the stage" or describe the general circumstances, without it necessarily being obvious which word they modify. "For a country that sees itself as egalitarian" means that the appearance of special privileges for the wealthy is particularly shocking, because the country's citizens tend to think that they have a pretty equal society.

The second sentence explains the first:

> those going to Gymnasium tend to be disproportionately well-off.

"Gymnasium" is a type of college preparatory school in Germany and Scandinavia. This is identifying the class privilege mentioned in the first part: children of the wealthy are more likely to get the education that prepares them for university.

Structurally, the two clauses are complete. Each one has a subject ("this" and "those") and a predicate (everything else). It's probably just confusing because the sentences are fused together with a dash rather than being clearly separated with a period.

Answer (score 2):

I've tagged the sentence with grammatical marks and brackets for clauses. Then I transformed it into something a little easier to mentally parse. (Bold words are for visual coordination and to see changed text.)

- For a country that sees itself as egalitarian, this smacks of class privilege—those going to Gymnasium tend to be disproportionately well-off.
- [**For** `a country that sees itself as egalitarian`<sup>NP</sup>], [`this`<sup>SUBJ1</sup> `smacks`<sup>V1</sup> `of class privilege`<sup>V1-Mod</sup>]—[`those going to Gymnasium`<sup>SUBJ2</sup> `tend to be`<sup>V2</sup> `disproportionately well-off`<sup>V2-Obj</sup>].
- [`This`<sup>SUBJ1</sup> `smacks`<sup>V1</sup> `of class privilege`<sup>V1-Mod</sup>]**:** [`those going to Gymnasium`<sup>SUBJ2</sup> `tend to be`<sup>V2</sup> `disproportionately well-off`<sup>V2-Obj</sup>] [**for** `a country that sees itself as egalitarian`<sup>NP</sup>].
- **`What`**`smacks of class privilege`<sup>SUBJ1</sup> ***is<sup>V1-Copula</sup> that*** [`those going to Gymnasium`<sup>SUBJ2</sup> `tend to be`<sup>V2</sup> `disproportionately well-off`<sup>V2-Obj</sup>], [***which contrasts with*** `a country that sees itself as egalitarian`<sup>NP</sup>].